# BeanSerializer/BeanDeserializer Axis Generated Object

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, xml-serialization, axis, xml-deserialization

I have a large number of axis generated objects from several WSDLs, I need a generic solution to store the objects in xml format in the database, but also load them back in java when needed. 
This is what I've made so far:

```
private String serializeAxisObject(Object obj) throws Exception {
    if (obj == null) {
        return null;
    }
    StringWriter outStr = new StringWriter();
    TypeDesc typeDesc = getAxisTypeDesc(obj);
    QName qname = typeDesc.getXmlType();
    String lname = qname.getLocalPart();
    if (lname.startsWith(">") && lname.length() > 1)
        lname = lname.substring(1);

    qname = new QName(qname.getNamespaceURI(), lname);
    AxisServer server = new AxisServer();
    BeanSerializer ser = new BeanSerializer(obj.getClass(), qname, typeDesc);
    SerializationContext ctx = new SerializationContext(outStr,
            new MessageContext(server));
    ctx.setSendDecl(false);
    ctx.setDoMultiRefs(false);
    ctx.setPretty(true);
    try {
        ser.serialize(qname, new AttributesImpl(), obj, ctx);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Unable to serialize object "
                + obj.getClass().getName(), e);
    }

    String xml = outStr.toString();
    return xml;
}

    private Object deserializeAxisObject(Class<?> cls, String xml)
        throws Exception {
    final String SOAP_START = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soapenv:Header /><soapenv:Body>";
    final String SOAP_START_XSI = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><soapenv:Header /><soapenv:Body>";
    final String SOAP_END = "</soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";

    Object result = null;
    try {
        Message message = new Message(SOAP_START + xml + SOAP_END);
        result = message.getSOAPEnvelope().getFirstBody()
                .getObjectValue(cls);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            Message message = new Message(SOAP_START_XSI + xml + SOAP_END);
            result = message.getSOAPEnvelope().getFirstBody()
                    .getObjectValue(cls);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            throw new Exception(e1);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private TypeDesc getAxisTypeDesc(Object obj) throws Exception {
    final Class<? extends Object> objClass = obj.getClass();
    try {
        final Method methodGetTypeDesc = objClass.getMethod("getTypeDesc",
                new Class[] {});
        final TypeDesc typeDesc = (TypeDesc) methodGetTypeDesc.invoke(obj,
                new Object[] {});
        return (typeDesc);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Unable to get Axis TypeDesc for "
                + objClass.getName(), e);
    }
}
```

I have fixed it, I will leave this here if anyone else needs to use it

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it, I will leave this here if anyone else needs to use it. See the updated version.

Thank you